# HTML video won't play in Firefox

Tags: .htaccess, html5-video

I have an html `<video>` tag with `.ogg`, `.mp4` and `.webm` type of videos. I've also edited the `.htaccess` with the appropriate `AddFile` types. My video is supposed to play in the background. In Chrome, IE and Opera works correctly but in Firefox not. Here is my code:

```
<div class = "bgvid">
        <video autoplay loop preload = "metadata" poster="images/pathos-lounge-restaurant.jpg" id="bgvid">
            <source src="media/Luxurios-Pathos-Sunset-Bar-Restaurant.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="media/Luxurios-Pathos-Sunset-Bar-Restaurant.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="media/Luxurios-Pathos-Sunset-Bar-Restaurant.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        </video>
    </div>
```

And here is my page: http://freebeachbar.gr/pathos/

Comment: I see in console --> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 1):

Two things

You have class `hidden` for container and lounge

and you have `overflow:hidden` for media all

You might wan't to remove that